# Table structure for reporting SQL Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not sure if this is the best structure for what I am trying to do.

I have 2 tables.

First table called Team which contains 3 columns, Team ID, Team Name and Kit Colour. This table contains data about the team only.

Second table called player name contains 3 columns, Player ID, Player name and Team ID. More columns will be added soon. Player table is about the player only. Team ID is the foreign key which links both tables together. A team can only have 15 players max so there can be 15 player entries for each team.

There can be thousands of teams with a maximum of 15 players each.

I have a horizontal Report that I need to fill that looks like this:

```
Team Name | Player 1 Name | Player 2 Name | Player 3 Name....| Player Name 15
```

My question is, I this best table structure set up for the report? How would I get data of a certain team with performance in mind? For example I want information for Team A, and all its players. There can be 15 players. If I can display the information in one select statement from left to right, I can easily fill in the report but this can t be done without using multiple selects which can be negative towards performance.

The other table structure that was suggested was having join both tables together instead of 2 table. A column for each player and their properties would have a column as well but this does not look correct as table would be massive and more player properties can be added.

I am using SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two separate tables one for team and one for players, since team attributes can be common for multiple players it's better to have them separated rather having all together and duplicating, in your case TeamID serves as the link between both team and player table. so two table with a one to many relation ship is your ideal choice in my opinion.

To retrieve the information of a specific team you can use a simple join and a select statement

```
SELECT *
FROM TEAM T
INNER JOIN Player P
on T.TeamID=P.TeamID
WHERE T.TeamID=''
```

Comment: This however returns multiple rows per team and it's difficult to fill in a horizontal report. I know the table structure is beneficial but it's the reporting part I am confused with.

Comment: You mean two records for same team id in team table

Comment: No there team ID is unique. My horizontal report need the team name and then all the players name in their own column. All in one row. It's like combining multiple rows from your example into one single row

Comment: Now I get it, what is your reporting tool.

Comment: The report involves me writing a SQL code and then the code will be added to a report in crystal report and the users will run that report.